# change source code of midi file

Tags: midi

I'm not a coder, so hopefully I can ask this in a way that makes sense to you guys! ;-)

Is there an easy way to modify the content of an individual midi file? For example, I have a midi file that lists [sets in stone, more like it] the key of the song as C, when it's really D.

I have plenty of midi programs that will let me change keys [and move notes]. That doesn’t fix my problem. The notes are in the right place the key is just mislabeled.

I thought I could just open the file in Atom and change the C to D and be done... but that didn't work. It's all gibberish in Atom.

I’m on a mac. Is there any way for me to modify the contents of my midi files?

Thanks, in advance, to any/all who respond!

Comment: I think you should research what the structure of a midi file is and change it with a binary/hex editor.
Anyway, I'm not sure if a midi file has a "key". I think it just has notes, durations and instruments, and only when you open it with a music program, it guesses the key. At least that's what I thought back then when I opened midi files with music programs. :)

Comment: I opened a midi file in a hex editor but that wasn't very enlightening. btw, I'm pretty sure the key is set in the file somehow. several midi programs display the key [all consistently wrong] and I don't think they're guessing on the fly because most songs are listed as C when they clearly aren't [not even close]

Comment: If you open another midi with those same programs, do they use a different key? Maybe they are just using C as default for every midi, as it has no sharps or flats. Of course just opening a midi won't help, that's why I first said you should do some research about the midi structure. ;)

Comment: the key stays consistent in each midi program I have, making me think it's in the file.

Comment: I did as much research as I could before coming here... I found articles about setting the key but none of them said anything about HOW they were doing it [as in what environment]. To a coder, maybe it was obvious. To me it was just confusing... that's why I ended up here!

Answer (score 1):

Most MIDI files do not store the key.

But when they do, they use a key signature event that can be represented in hex as `FF 59 02 sf mi`, where `sf` is the number of sharps (positive) or flats (negative), and `mi` is 0/1 for major/minor.

If some file does not have this event, you have to add it. The easiest way to do this would be to use some SMF library for the programming language of your choice.

Comment: thanks! if most midi files don't store key info, is C the default? that would explain why most are in the key of C, I would think.

Comment: There is no official default, but 0/0 sounds like obvious default values.

Comment: found a program, MidiYodi, that lets me change the key very easily!